# Support for unicode characters in slug fields

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using a prepopulated_fields in my admin which it should copy the value of title to slug, however my title is in persian and i need the url to be in the same language:

admin.py

```
prepopulated_fields = {"url": ("title",)}
```

result:

```
title = تست
url = tst
```

desired result:

```
title = تست
url = تست
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, in Django 1.8 and below.

Django 1.9 [has added support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SlugField.allow_unicode) for unicode characters in slug fields, using a `allow_unicode` parameter. That will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm using django 1.10 with allow_unicode  but it's not working with utf8 words